# POST works in Postman but not in browser

Tags: asp.net-web-api, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have this in vuejs using axios

```
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:64427/api/Authenticate/Token',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
      quad: this.quad,
      password: this.password
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.header.token);
  })
```

When i post using the endpoint in postman, it works

> http://localhost:64427/api/Authenticate/Token?quad=YGOP&password=P@ssw0rd

But i can 404 error code when i am posting using axios. 
[image]

Here is the backend

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Token")]
[BasicAuthentication]
public HttpResponseMessage Login(string quad, string password)
{
    bool isAuthenticated = EmployeeSecurity.Login(quad, password);
    if(isAuthenticated)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal != null && Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var basicAuthenticationIdentity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
            if (basicAuthenticationIdentity != null)
            {
                var username = basicAuthenticationIdentity.Name;
                return GetAuthToken(username);
            }
            return null;

        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: The URL you are hitting through Postman has data in the URL parameters, but the other one has data in the body. 

Can you share the code of your API Action for further details?

Comment: You seems to using method "GET" via postman, and "POST" via axios

Comment: @csblo you can use query params with the post method

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Yes, that's for this reason that I don't send that as an answer :)

Comment: @csblo Both are set to POST

Comment: @IpsitGaur i updated the post with the API action

Comment: don't send usernames and passwords in URLs, that's security 101. Anyone can intercept the requests and steal that data. Send them in the body of the request and make sure the request is sent over https, so headers and body are encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your backend to accept the model you are sending from the client, you can do this by adding a class LoginData containing the 2 properties and put that in the Login function and use the FromBody attribute to map it from the body and not the url.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Token")]
        [BasicAuthentication]
        public HttpResponseMessage Login([FromBody] LoginData login)
        {
            bool isAuthenticated = EmployeeSecurity.Login(login.quad, login.password);
            if (isAuthenticated)
            {
                if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal != null && Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var basicAuthenticationIdentity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
                    if (basicAuthenticationIdentity != null)
                    {
                        var username = basicAuthenticationIdentity.Name;
                        return GetAuthToken(username);
                    }
                    return null;

                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public class LoginData
        {
            public string quad { get; set; }

            public string password { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your postman post uses parameters to pass the username and password `?quad=YGOP&password=P@ssw0rd`, whereas your axios post uses the payload/body to pass the data

```
data: {
  quad: this.quad,
  password: this.password
}
```

try changing this line:

```
url: 'http://localhost:64427/api/Authenticate/Token?quad=' + this.quad + '&password=' + this.password,
```

and then set `data` to `{}`

Comment: It will work but is not a good practice to send data through URL parameters if you are using POST

Comment: i never said it was good practice, but as i cant see the backend/api, thats the only solution i can provide